# How to send apprequest using actionscript without FB.ui or PHP?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I am building an App in Flash using graph API, I would like to post a request to increase count next to the app bookmark (as detailed here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/), all the documentation refer to either:

1. server-side (PHP SDK) where there is no problem using the 'app secret' to retrieve app_access_token, or
2. using FB.ui which requires user interaction, which is not what I am trying to do.

Is there a way to send an apprequests (App to User) via JS SDK only?

Could it be that this feature does not work in sandbox mode?

---

UPDATE: solved. worked it out.

I use the server to retrieve the app_access_token (only for a valid logged in user), once having app_access_token there is no problem using standard api calls from within flash.

Comment: If you've found the answer, you should post it in the "Answers" section and accept it. Not edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: solved. worked it out.

I use the server to retrieve the app_access_token (only for a valid logged in user), once having app_access_token there is no problem using standard api calls from within flash.